# drawing a line between two table cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

My homework was to create a scipt that connects two marked cells of a table. My solution works fine, but the result line is a bit disproportionate.

[image]

As you can see, the last row is 4-cells long while all other rows are 3-cells long. But I'd like the middle part of a line to be the longest. Like this:

[image]

How to get the desired result and not make the code too complicated. The code itself:

```js
function connectThem() {
  if (markedCells.length == 2) {
    y_distance = markedCells[0][0] - markedCells[1][0];
    y_distance = Math.abs(y_distance) + 1; // vertial distance

    x_distance = markedCells[0][1] - markedCells[1][1];
    x_distance = Math.abs(x_distance) + 1; // horizontal distance

    if (x_distance > y_distance) { // if horizontal distance greater than vertical distance
      x_distance -= 0;
      alert("horizontal connection");

      totalRows = y_distance;

      for (var row = 0; row < y_distance; row++) {
        thisRowLength = Math.floor(x_distance / totalRows);

        for (var c = 0; c < thisRowLength; c++) {
          document.getElementById('cell-' + markedCells[0][0] + '-' + markedCells[0][1]).style.backgroundColor = "red";

          markedCells[0][1] = parseInt(markedCells[0][1]) + 1;
        }

        markedCells[0][0] = parseInt(markedCells[0][0]) + 1;

        totalRows -= 1; // vertical remaining
        x_distance -= thisRowLength; // horizontal remaining
      }
    } else {
      y_distance -= 0;
      alert("vertical or horizontal connection");

      totalCols = x_distance;

      for (var col = 0; col < x_distance; col++) {
        thisColLength = Math.floor(y_distance / totalCols);

        for (var r = 0; r < thisColLength; r++) {

          document.getElementById('cell-' + markedCells[0][0] + '-' + markedCells[0][1]).style.backgroundColor = "red";

          markedCells[0][0] = parseInt(markedCells[0][0]) + 1;
        }

        markedCells[0][1] = parseInt(markedCells[0][1]) + 1;

        totalCols -= 1;
        y_distance -= thisColLength;
      }
    }

    alert("x distance: " + x_distance + "    y distance: " + y_distance);
  } else {
    alert("Can't connect " + markedCells.length + " cells together :-(")
  }
}


var htmlElements = ""; // storing the whole table here

for (var r = 1; r < 41; r++) { // creating the table row by row
  htmlElements += '<tr>';

  for (var c = 1; c < 61; c++) { // and column by column
    htmlElements += '<td class="tCell white" id="cell-' + r.toString() + '-' + c.toString() + '"></td>';
  }

  htmlElements += '</tr>'
}


var theTable = document.getElementById("tab");
theTable.innerHTML = htmlElements;

var allTableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td"); // adding all cells to an array
var markedCells = [] // storing marked cells here

for (var i = 0; i < allTableCells.length; i++) {
  allTableCells[i].addEventListener("click", function() { // when click any cell
    let stringID = this.id.split('-');

    if (this.className == "tCell white") {
      this.className = "tCell red";
      markedCells.push([stringID[1], stringID[2]]);
    } else {
      this.className = "tCell white";

      let index = markedCells.indexOf([stringID[1], stringID[2]]);
      markedCells.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log(markedCells);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -450px;
  margin-top: -300px;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <table id="tab">

  </table>
</div>

<button id="btn" onclick="connectThem()">Connect!</button>
```

Comment: What should the connect button do besides your example?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I'm gonna add some more function to it

Comment: You might want to look into Bresenham's line drawing algorithm - https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html

Comment: If you select first cell on right and then cell on left, the line doesn't connect them